# integration of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, integral

I do need to calculate a vector of integrals
What is the most productive way to implement it in R? I have

```
F2 <- function(beta, z1, z2){
    f2 <- function(eps){ some formmula }
    return(f2)
}
```

I am doing now

```
k<-integrate(F2(beta, z1, z2),  lower=-z1%*%beta[1:4], upper=Inf)$value
```

But I need to calculate integrals for matrices X1 and X2 and the result should be a vector, i.e. to take integral for each row

I will optimize by beta, so it should use all betas and then each row from z1 and z2

I am doing it in loop, but I think there are some build in functions, as mupply....

I am trying to use

```
 z1<-function(beta, z1, z2) { 
    sapply(beta, function(beta) {
    integrate(F2(beta,z1,z2),  lower=-z1%*%beta[1:4], upper=Inf)$value
  })
}
```

error- the limit is missing

Comment: I am trying to use     scores <- mapply(integ, beta.start, x1, x2)
but then I think it uses only some elements of beta.start, but I want all of them

Comment: I am trying z1<-integrate(function(beta) { 
  sapply(beta, function(beta) {
    integrate(function(x) F2(beta.start1,x1,x2), lower=-x1%*%beta.start1[1:4], upper=Inf)$value
  })
}, x1, x2) but have a mistake